# How to cancel the delayed thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading, ios-multithreading

I am executing set of tasks, and in order to span them over time I've used `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: ... )` It adds pauses between executions.

Then, on the main screen I have controllers, that can intervene into thread execution, so when controller applied I want to cancel the sleep. And start from the place of user's choice.
So, I've tried
`Thread.exit()` - and it terminates the program with error.

How to exit (or, refresh) the current thread and start from the place I want?
What are the ways to control the suspension of thread by button (i.e. controller)?

What actually happens is that if I cancel, it continues to run just from the same place...

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Actions Queue")
let delay: Double = 5
var actions = ["action 1", "action 2", "action 3", "action 4", "action 5"]


// every time task finishes, it calls for the following task (with delay)
queue.sync {
// sets an interval, that continues an action
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval(delay))
    // continue an action
}

// heres how I've tried in main view, but it doesn't work
queue.sync {
    Thread.current.cancel()
}
```

**EDITS:**

For example, what does the `cancel()` do here? and why `exit()` can't be applied to `Thread.current`, but only to `Thread.`

"You can use these semantics to cancel the execution of a thread or determine if the thread is still executing or has finished its task". Okey, if I `cancel()`. What, then will *start* it again?

```
queue.sync {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval(10.0))
    // do something
}

Button("...") {
    queue.sync {
        Thread.current.cancel()
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread

Comment: Tell me in the comments, if I have to improve the question; so that I know how I can fix it for better quality discussion

Comment: I think you're mixing GCD with Threads. While they're targetting similar goals they are on completely different levels so it's never a good idea to mix them. I'd suggest you to use either [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch) with [work items](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem) or [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) with a set of [Operations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) if you need more complex interaction between your tasks.

Comment: @ScorpiCon what I am trying to achieve is - having a presentation that runs with predetermined time between slides, but if user wants to go back(or forward); it should cut straight away to previous slide and continue in the same manner of predetermined pauses. Do you have some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, I would advise against sleeping on a thread. First, we do not have preemptive cancelation. Second, it’s an inefficient use of resources, tying up that thread unnecessarily.

If you want to do something after a certain period of time, you have a few options:

1. Schedule a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) and then [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate) it if you want to stop it.
2. If using Swift concurrency (e.g., `Task`, `async`-`await`, etc.), you can [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862701-sleep/), which, unlike `Thread.sleep`, detects and handles cancelation. `Thread.sleep` should be avoided, but with Swift concurrency, you can store the `Task` in a property, `cancel` it when appropriate, and `Task.sleep` within the `Task` will handle cancellation elegantly.
3. You can create a [`DispatchWorkItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem), dispatch it with [`asyncAfter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter), and then [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) if you don’t want that to happen.

If you have some cancelable tasks that you want to perform every *x* seconds, a single repeating `Timer` is probably easiest, as you can `invalidate` it and it stops the whole repeating series in one step. (It also avoids timer coalescing problems.)

---

You said:

> what I am trying to achieve is - having a presentation that runs with predetermined time between slides, but if user wants to go back (or forward); it should cut straight away to previous slide and continue in the same manner of predetermined pauses.

I would suggest a repeating `Timer` to advance to the next slide. If the user manually changes to another slide, `invalidate` the old timer and create a new repeating `Timer`.

Comment: Thank you for answer and links to research reading! Made it to me way more clear! Currently trying to implement properly this functionality with Timer. The response time of the program 1000x times faster than with Threading.

Comment: Cool. FWIW, GCD pattern shouldn't be slower, but for something repeating that you want to cancel, `Timer` is just a much easier way to do it. There probably was something else going on in your GCD implementation, but I guess it doesn't matter now that you've got a better solution cooking...